# 'IndexError: list index out of range' when applying lambda function to a column in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, split, index-error

I have a pandas dataframe in which one of the columns contains address information and I want to slice the address to only provide the zipcode and put this into a new column. For example a typical address looks like this:

> 609 Lizeth Streets Bolton MA 01740 US.

To grab the zip I tried:

```
split_zip = lambda x: str(x).split()[-2]
df['Zipcode'] = df['Address'].apply(split_zip)
```

Doing that I get an

> 'IndexError: list index out of range'

Sidenote: When I don't specify an index, it will put the split list in the column just as I would expect (i.e. [609, Lizeth, Streets, Bolton, MA, 01740, US]). I can see that the zip is in the [-2] position and I just don't know why it won't grab it. Additionally, trying to grab the [1] index also throws the same error. The only index that seems to work is when I use [-1] which grabs 'US'

I'm fairly new to python and working with data in pandas so any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: It sounds like some row in your dataframe just contains "US", so when it's split there is no second-to-last element. Hard to say for sure without access to the data, though.

Comment: so I checked to see if there was a second-to-last element by not specifying an index and it puts a list in each row with all the elements you would expect. There definitely should be a second-to-last element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a way you can try:

```
df['Zipcode'] = df['Address'].str.split(' ').str[-2]
```

Comment: You are my savior! This worked but I am not sure how this is different than from my original. Any thoughts?

Comment: Not sure why your solution was failing, incase this helped please accept and upvote:)

Comment: @JacobGarwin your solution fails because it uses a `lambda`. `str(x).split()` is a `list` and since you try to index with -2, where it doesn't exist there's no additional error handling. On the other hand `Series.str` has additional error handling such that when you try to access `Series.str[N]` it returns `NaN` as opposed to an IndexError when `N` is outside of the range. You can see the additional error handling in the source. It's a simple if-else logic block: https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/62a87bf4a2af02a8d3bc271ad26e5994292b8e6a/pandas/core/strings.py#L1672-L1729

Comment: Sadly I can't upvote since my reputation is too low... but definitely will accept. Thanks again!